# Spring RestTemplate POST method without body

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I am trying to write a client in which I will do the POST method without body.
Is the only solution to insert null?
example:

```
client.exchange("/" + userId + "/logout", HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class);
```

Comment: why would you do a POST without a body rather than a GET first of all?

Comment: @LucaTampellini The only scenario I can think of is if you don't have control of the API and it was implemented poorly. Of course, in that case, you have no choice.

Answer (score 5):

You can also pass `HttpEntity.EMPTY` (or `new HttpEntity<>(null)`) there - the result should be the same.

If you have `HttpHeaders` object - you can also pass it into the corresponding constructor: `new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders)`

Comment: I cant do new HttpEntity() because protected HttpEntity()

Comment: Forgot about it, sorry - I've updated my answer